# Eclipse: Some or all projects can not be imported because they already exist in the workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I'm sorry, I know that question is asked quite often. But non of the scenarios suits my problem.

I'm using Eclipse (in Win7) with Git. Within a Git-branch I created a new project. Then I switched back on the master-branch. There the project is not in the workspace. But when I want to add it, I get the following error:

> Some or all projects can not be imported because they already exist in
>   the workspace

My problem is, that the project is NOT in the workspace - as seen in Eclipse. But sure, it's on the hard disk, because it's part of my Git repository. So I can't delete it there. According to other posts, I removed it from this folder:

> C:\Development\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects

But still I can't re-add it to the Eclipse workspace. Any idea?

Comment: Use file --> import to import the project to eclipse workspace.

Comment: That's what I did! Import --> from Git --> local repo. It finds the project, but I can't check/select it because it says the error mentioned above.

Comment: Use "file" --> "import" -->"Existing Projects into Workspace" to import the Project that exists on your HDD

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Post it as an answer and I will accept it, so that you gain the reputation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "file" --> "import" -->"Existing Projects into Workspace" to import the Project that exists on your HDD

Answer (score 8):

This usually happens when you change the project directory physically without first delete in Eclipse.
You can view and delete these hidden projects in the following view:

```
Window -> Show View -> Other -> Navigator
```

Then simply just continue with the process of import existing project.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to `Window-> Perspective -> Open Perspective -> Java EE`
2. Right click on the desired project and remove it
3. Go to `File -> Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace`

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the project is created in the directory and that you are not filtering the projects by the Working Set.

I hope this can help, I didn't realize that I was filtering through the **Working Set** and that's why I couldn't import the project, because it was already imported but I just didn't see it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Window -> Show View -> Project Explorer

After that, right click on the project name and Delete :)